# How to create a list of checkboxes

Tags: python, qt, checkbox, pyqt, qlistwidget

I'm trying to read in an xml file and populate a `QListWidget` with some of its contents. Each entry should have a checkbox.

In Qt Designer I created the list and added an item that has a checkbox by adding the item to the listWidget, then right clicking on it and selecting Edit Items > Properties > Set Flags to UserCheckable. So i can do it manually.

But when I read in the xml file to populate the ListWidget I can't make these items checkable.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

xml_file = os.path.join(path, testcase_file)
tree = et.parse(xml_file)
root = tree.getroot()

for testcases in root.iter('testcase'):
    testcase_name = str(testcases.attrib)
    item = self.listWidgetTestCases
    item.addItem(QtGui.QApplication.translate("qadashboard", testcase_name, None))
    # item.setFlags(item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
    # item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
```

This creates a list of test case name in the list-widget. However I can't make these items into checkboxes. `item.setFlags` or `ItemIsUserCheckable` is not recognised for list Widgets, so the two lines are commented out in the above example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're almost there: it's just that you're trying to make the [list-widget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html) checkable, rather than each [list-widget-item](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem.html).

Try this instead:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

self.listWidgetTestCases = QtWidgets.QListWidget()

for testcases in root.iter('testcase'):
    testcase_name = str(testcases.attrib)

    item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(testcase_name)
    item.setFlags(item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
    item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
    self.listWidgetTestCases.addItem(item)
```

(NB: for PyQt4, use QtGui instead of QtWidgets)